# How to add or remove files/code from Angular build depending not on environment but on target?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, polyfills

I need to add IE 10+ support for my Angular application.
I've already succeeded in doing almost all of the work - I've enabled correct polyfills, created additional dev build configuration with es5 target to test things etc. My application successfully runs on IE with one exception. I have nosleep.js library that is needed to avoid screen lock on mobile devices. If the library is attached to the project, IE fails to parse its code, so even dirty things like dynamic require don't work:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class NoSleepService {
  noSleepEnabled = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  enable() {
    if(!this.noSleepEnabled) {
      const noSleep = require('nosleep.js');

      const noSleepObject = new noSleep();

      this.noSleepEnabled = true;
      noSleepObject.noSleepVideo.muted = true;
      noSleepObject.enable();

      console.log("Enabled nosleep", noSleepObject);
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe for this particular library, there is some other workaround. But I'm not sure that I won't run into the same issues with the other required libraries in the future, so I would like to have some common solution.
That is, I would like to exclude library code from the build if the target is es5. So, I can't put this into the environment variables, since I have es6 and es5 targets for both dev/prod environments.
Is there a way to change files/code included based on target/build configured in angular.json?

Comment: Why don't you dynamically add the script to the page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm 50% sure this won't work :), but have you tried `try catch`?

```
enable() {
  if(!this.noSleepEnabled) {
    try {
      const noSleep = require('nosleep.js');
      // ..
    } catch {
      // apparently this is IE
    }
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can also use load the [script](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/blob/master/dist/NoSleep.min.js) from inside your `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<script src="NoSleep.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

---

Ultimate and best solution would be to drop IE support all together and unite as a strong front against anyone who has such a horrendous request!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I think it should work for similar cases in the future, currently, I've just reworked library code a little and forced it to compile with the build. Yes, you are right that we should not encourage IE usage. But before I implemented IE support I haven't had strong arguments, I couldn't just say "It's a crap, tell that client with 100 users that we won't support it". And now when I can show how slowly the app works on IE 11 with glitches, how ugly it is on IE 10 and 9, I have strong arguments. I've spent a day of work on it not to spend months in the future.